# facebook like button plugin onclick popup distorted and overflowed

Tags: facebook

I have included the facebook like plugin

I have added below the title of my article.

The like button is displayed well and is working but...

When we click like a popup appears so that the user can post some comment.
That popup is distorted and the content is overflowed and the publish and close buttons for that popup are away from the layout.

**Here is a screen shot...**

[image]

I have added a border to the div which contains the facebook plugin html code.

Here is the live url where you can see the problem.

I was checking in firefox 9

In that popup i cannot see the publish and close buttons.

**here is the live url**

http://vikku.info/programming/chrome-extension/get-selected-text-send-to-web-server-in-chrome-extension-communicate-between-content-script-and-background-page.htm

sample code

```
<div class="fblike" style="border:1px solid red;">
<fb:like href="http://vikku.info/programming/chrome-extension/get-selected-text-send-to-web-server-in-chrome-extension-communicate-between-content-script-and-background-page.htm" send="false" show_faces="false" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
</div>
```

also you can view source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this CSS from your style in your head section of your page and it will popup fine.

```
/* for facebook width 100% */
iframe.fb_ltr { width:100% !important; }
```